# Ubuntu 16.04 menus not displaying properly and desktop background black

Tags: 16.04, menu

The menu icons on my ubuntu 16.04 are not displaying correctly.

For example the sliding bars are missing from the sound menu below.

[image: sound menu not displaying]

Also my Ubuntu background keeps going black.

Output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: when is this behaviour started? was it ok before?

Comment: yes everything was working fine for the last year yesterday this started happening.

Comment: have you changed any system files or edited theme files some thing like that?

Comment: No not that I am aware of. I changed the monitor though then changed it back.

Comment: if you change any background now and reboot what is happening?

Comment: If I run `nautilus -q` the background comes back but disappears shortly afterwards. The menu are still broken. Restarting does not do anything.

Comment: what is the output of `xrandr` you used the present monitor last year.. for some time used the other monitor and now you are with last year monitor.. rite.. are both monitors resolution same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87748/discussion-between-pratap-and-cherry-aldi).